# Spring myBatis same session in Oracle for multiple users

Tags: spring, oracle, session, mybatis

My web application is using Spring and myBatis and Tomcat server. While analyzing, we are facing one issue. When ever tomcat requests Oracle, first time it is creating the new oracle session (SID) for First user. For second user, it is assigning the same session which first user is using.

First user is using the session id - 200
Second user is getting assigned the session id - 200

First user is updating some value - 200 (same session id)

Like that it is using the same session id irrespective of how many users using this application.

I want to create each individual session for each user. I am using the sqlSessionFactory in my persistence xml.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: You should provide more material to expect an answer. What I read here, let me think issue could be related to the datasource configuration in Tomcat.

Comment: Problem with your Annotation, Please go through spring scopes.